# Replacing a variable in prolog

Tags: prolog

In prolog I have two rules `gender(male,[man,boy]).` and `gender(female,[woman,girl]).` as well as having `gen(female)` and `gen(male)`. I then pass in a variable to see what the user has inputted as follows:

```
whatgender(X):-
    gen(X).

whatgender(X):-
    gender(Pass,Out),
    member(X,Out).
```

`Pass` is now what I want `X` to be. Unfortunately due to how I manipulate it after this I need the variable to be X and can't create another variable to Out e.g. `whatgender(X,Pass)`. Is there any way to do this or am I going to have to use a different approach?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Your first `whatgender/1` clause has a particular domain/meaning for its argument, which appears to be `male` or `female`. Then in your second `whatgender/1` clause, you've mixed it around and now the argument (`X`) seems to mean `boy`, `man`, `girl` or `woman`. I'm not sure how you would fix this since it's not clear to me what `whatgender/1` is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @lurker sorry is unclear. With input X I'm trying to see if X is male or female, If X is either of them then great, move on. X however could also be boy,man or woman,girl. If it is then X should be changed to Male or Female respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog, once a variable is instantiated (assigned a specific value) within a given *predicate clause*, it cannot be reassigned except through backtracking. In other words, this would always fail:

```
foo(X) :- X = b.

?- X = a, foo(X).
```

It fails because `a` and `b` are two different atoms, and `foo` attempts to unify `a` with `b`. This is more clearly seen if you simply queried `foo(a)`. How would `foo` possibly rebind a value of `b` to an atom `a`? It's not even meaningful.

A fundamental issue is that your predicate is trying to treat a single variable two different ways. One way to resolve this is to refactor `whatgender` so that it means the same thing in both case. We can do this by using two arguments:

```
whatgender(X, X) :-
    gen(X).
whatgender(X, Y) :-
    gender(Y, Out),
    member(X, Out).
```

Now, `whatgender(X, Y)` means that `Y` is the specific gender represented by `X`. The first clause is the trivial case.

What this means, though, is that if you start off with `X` and it is bound to a value, then you need to "map" it to the specific gender, `Y`, you are now needing to use `Y` for that purpose (the "specific" gender).

```
% Code using X (more general value but specifically bound)
whatgender(X, Y),

% Code using X for more general, but Y for the specific gender
```

Per my initial comment, you absolutely cannot do this:

```
% Code using X (more general value but specifically bound)
whatgender(X),  % "assign" a new value to X
                % THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I do however need the first and second clauses output to be the same, either both x or both y, is this possible?

Comment: @MrU As I said in the first paragraph, once a variable is instantiated, it cannot be re-instantiated. So, no, it is not possible.